# Minimal polynomial of $\alpha=a+b\sqrt d$ where $d$ is square free

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Here are two first steps that could be used to compute the integral closure of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$:

(1) Reduce to the case when $d$ is square free.

(2) If $\alpha=a+b\sqrt d$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Q$, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $x^2-2ax+(a^2-b^2d)$. Thus $\alpha$ lies in the integral closure iff $2a,a^2-b^2d\in\mathbb Z$.

---

(1) How to do this? Assume $d$ is not square-free. Let's say $d=p^2q$. Then $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]=\mathbb Z[p\sqrt q]$. How to reduce to the case when $d$ is square free? I don't think the integral closure of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ equals the integral closure of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt q]$.

(2) Isn't the notion of a minimal polynomial defined over a ring? This is a minimal polynomial over which ring? If over $\mathbb Z$, then $2a,a^2-b^2d$ are always integers, so I don't understand this step.

Answer (score 2):

Useful Fact : if $R_3$ is integral over $R_2$ and $R_2$ is integral over $R_1$ then $R_3$ is integral over $R_1$

1) Suppose $d$ is not square free then $d=s^2t$ where $t$ is square free. Observe that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt t]$ is integral over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d] $ and hence the two have the same integral closure in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$

2) $\mathbb Z$ is integrally closed as it is a UFD. So if $\alpha \in$ integral closure of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ then all conjugates of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$ are also integral and hence the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ are integral over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ and hence over $\mathbb Z$. But the coefficients are in $\mathbb Q$ so they are elements of $\mathbb Q$ which are integral over $\mathbb Z$ and hence $\in \mathbb Z$